# MongoDB get value of element $in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update documents in MongoDB, or create them if they do not exist. For example (I am using mongoose with node, but I think that it should look pretty similar in MongoDB)

```
some_model.update({some_field: { $in: ['foo1','foo2'] } ,
                  { $setOnInsert :  { bar : 'NEW'} },
                  { multi : true, upsert : true });
```

Would it be possible to replace 'NEW' with an element of above array if none of my documents contain some_field with value of that element, or would I need to run multiple queries for that?

Comment: Can you expand on this with an actual example (for both cases where it upserts and where it updates)?  Couldn't you use $addToSet or is the value you want to $push different than the ones you are testing for?  The other thing is multi and upsert make no sense since multi says "update several documents" and upsert says "insert one" (new one)

Comment: You are right, I just tested it and it always creates just one document(I wanted to create new document for each element of an array that does not match any of my documents), so it seems that it can't be done in this way.

Comment: do you want a single new document with both fields being tested for or two documents, one for each?  If the latter then you are right, that cannot be done.  You would have to run the upsert for each of them.  One optimization is you can run regular update with list, and then when you check how many documents were updated, if it's 0 then you would iterate over the list re-running the update for each as an upsert (this is to make it thread safe, in case other threads are also doing the same updates).

Comment: Yes, I would like one for each. Thanks for all the help, how can I accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to insert a single document when you provide an `{upsert:true}` option to an update statement.   Since in your case you want to either update all matching documents or insert one for each element you test for, what you can do is this:

Run your regular update with list of elements, and then when you check how many documents were updated, if it's 0 then iterate over the list of elements, re-running the update for each of them as an upsert. This is to make it thread safe, in case other threads are also doing the same updates at the same time.